# How to work with float variables at asm in VS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I need to write a common task with inline asm: The Code I used is as Follows.

```
Vector3 Matrix3x3::objectToInertial(const Vector3 &v) 
{
    return Vector3(
        m11 * v.x + m12 * v.y + m13 * v.z,
        m21 * v.x + m22 * v.y + m23 * v.z,
        m31 * v.x + m32 * v.y + m33 * v.z
        );
}
```

How to make this equation with `asm: m11 * v.x + m12 * v.y`?

Comment: And your question is? And you have tried what? And you get an error where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to compute m11 * v.x + m12 * v.y by inline assembler try this (I am assuming you want to store the result in a variable result):

```
__asm
{
   fld m11
   fmul v.x
   fld m12
   fmul v.y
   faddp st(1), st
   fstp result
}
```

If you want to learn more about floating point arithmetic in assembly you can take a look at [Art of Assembly Language - Chapter 14](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/ch14/CH14-1.html) - you can download the book also as pdf it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#if *MICROSOFT_COMPILER_DETECTION*
#define APP_FORCEINLINE __forceinline
#else
#if *GCC_COMPILER_DETECTION*
#define APP_FORCEINLINE inline
#else
#define APP_FORCEINLINE /* */
#endif
#endif

APP_FORCEINLINE
Vector3 Matrix3x3::objectToInertial(const Vector3 &v) {
return Vector3(
    m11 * v.x + m12 * v.y + m13 * v.z,
    m21 * v.x + m22 * v.y + m23 * v.z,
    m31 * v.x + m32 * v.y + m33 * v.z
    );
```

Keep in mind that inlining is just a *suggestion* to the compiler, albeit it, a strong one.

The optimizing compilers of today may benefit from using different data structures than the Matrix3x3 class in use here.  XNAMATH.X (from Microsoft XNA) is designed to be cross-platform, and to take advantage of built-in intrinsics for math operations, when available for your requested CPU.

Comment: The OP is asking about using inline asm, not making the function `inline`.

Comment: @ildjarn, I understand that.  But this way, the compiler can do a better job than most programmers, and as good a job as the remaining few.

Comment: Possibly, but that doesn't change the fact that you're answering a question that wasn't asked ;-]